# Covert SD Card to be Readonly

Tags: java, android, swing, io, filesystems

Currently I am working on one project. I am not very sure where I've to post below qus in SO. Can you help me out below requirement:

- Write files in SD Card. - (Done)
- Users should not write content in SD Card's. - No Idea what to do
- Only app can write content[Optional]  - No Idea what to do [I may not possible if above step is successful]

I write a program using Java Swings, because It can be cross platform. If you have any suggestions let me know.

Edited:

- Only app can write content[Optional]  - No Idea what to do [I may not possible if above step is successful]

I'm encrypting the data before write into SD Card. How to prevent to delete files or modify files from SD Card.

Answer (score 1):

The normal way to make an SD card read-only is to slide the write protect switch to the on position.  However, that leaves you with a problem: your app won't be able to modify the card either.

I don't think that is possible to make an SD Card write protected (read only) in application software alone.  Especially if the card could be plugged into a "rooted" device, or a normal PC.  But what you could make it difficult for someone to update your data by using a combination of obfuscation and encryption to protect the data.

---

It appears that some software tools exist that claim to write protect SD cards.  It appears that these tools are actually just tweaking the ACLs for the root directory of the SD card.  (There is an obvious flaw in this as a security / protection mechanism.  The user can trivially reverse this using the Drive Properties dialog; see https://datarecovery.wondershare.com/flashdrive-recovery/read-only-flash-drive.html, for example.)

However, if this kind of "protection" is good enough for you, can make the relevant ACL changes from Java using the [`AclFileAttributeView`](https://docs.oracle.com/javase/7/docs/api/java/nio/file/attribute/AclFileAttributeView.html) interface.  The javadocs include some example code that a Java programmer could be adapt for your purposes.  I will leave that to you to do.

Comment: We are protecting the data using encryption, but what if user unfortunately delete the files.

Comment: Then they don't have the files anymore.  They could send the SD card back to you to be restored ... or reformat it an use if for something else.  How is this conceptually different to someone destroying a DVD with sandpaper?  The user has interfered with your product and broken it.  Not your problem ....

Comment: But I oberved some of softwares are doing same, then how they are doing? Guide me.

Answer (score 0):

I am not sure if this will work,but if possible give this a try:
**Right Click** on **Drive letter** in Windows and go to **Properties**.

Choose "**Security**", then under "**User**" or "**Group**", choose "**Everyone**" and then "**Edit**".
Now Under permissions tab set it to read and uncheck others.

Source:  https://datarecovery.wondershare.com/flashdrive-recovery/read-only-flash-drive.html

Comment: I am trying to do use tryLock() and other process, I'll update my ans.